# Finding out the cause of traffic change

Tags: google-analytics

I'm familiar with Google Analytics quite well, but still can't figure out how to do something that seems pretty basic.

Let's say I have a traffic increase of 20% on a certain month. Let's assume this represents about 10k increase in terms of visits. How can I understand what are the most significant contributors to the traffic increase - which pages, which acquisition sources, which search keywords, countries, etc'?

Theoretically, I can go over each section and check which entries had the most change, but beyond the reports being very cumbersome, it doesn't really provide a full picture. Ideally, I would like a report that says - of the 10k increase in visits, 5k came from an increase in "abc" search keyword, 30% came from an increase in traffic from France, and 20% came from a "xyz" acquisition campaign.

Would be happy to understand if there is a simple solution - whether inside GA or with an external tool - before I start hacking something like this for myself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the 'Intelligence Events' tab.

If that doesn't clarify it, set your date to the month in question, check the 'compare to' and select 'previous period' or 'previous year' and see how your channels or mediums compare. Then segment that channel/medium by source.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It certainly gives me the insights I was looking for, though I can't compare periods in this view.